# How to remove Xubuntu notification style?

Tags: unity, xubuntu, uninstall, notification, notify-osd

I downloaded Xubuntu to try it on Ubuntu. After uninstalling it using

```
sudo apt-get purge xubuntu-desktop
```

I found out that even after that when there were pop-up notifications, it would appear in  Xubuntu style. I want it to use the default style. How do I do that?

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyd` should remove the xfce notification program. The Ubuntu default notification program is `notify-osd`; that should be installed, install it if not. Then logout and login again.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge xubuntu-desktop xfce4`